# get max of two related colums of the same table with hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, greatest-n-per-group, hibernate-criteria

Using hibernate criteria, and with the next table:

```
user  category  subcategory
A     1         1
A     1         2
B     1         1
B     2         1
```

¿What is the best way to obtain the users with the max category and max subcategory?

The criteria must return:

```
A     1         2
B     2         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this question with two subCriterias one for each column:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class, "c");

DetachedCriteria subCrit1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Participante.class, "s1")
    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("s1.user", "c.user"))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.max("s1.category")));

criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("c.category", subCrit1 ));

DetachedCriteria subCrit2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class, "s2")
    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("s2.user", "c.user"))
    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("s2.category", "c.category"))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.max("s2.subcategory")));

criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("c.subcategory", subCrit2));
```